# ExtJS: Removing unnecessary form item scrollbars in Firefox

Tags: css, extjs, overflow, scrollbars

I am seeking some advice regarding unnecessary scrollbars appearing on certain form items. A screenshot of the issue appears below. Note it is the right-most scrollbar that is unnecessary.

[bad_scrollbars http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/9307/scrollfu.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/9307/scrollfu.png)

The culprit appears to be the following css, adding `overflow: auto;` to form items within windows in gecko-based browsers (the problem appears on Firefox):

```
.ext-gecko .x-window-body .x-form-item {
    outline: medium none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Removing this style solves the problem, but I am wary of possible side effects - though I haven't noticed any as yet, this style was obviously included for a reason.

Does anyone who knows more about Ext styling know if overriding this css to remove the `overflow: auto;` style will cause other problems?

As an aside, this is only an issue (so far) with a certain component - a custom extension of the Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect component - even though other components use more vertical space. Does anyone know of a possible reason for this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are there any "unusual" margins added to that component? It has to be calculating the top level height and the child element height slightly differently, I would have thought.

Comment: looking at the screenshot, I can see some content creaping in at the bottom of the area with the scrollbar; some black pixels. Scrollbars only appear if there isn't enough room to put all the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow: auto tells the browser to add a scrollbar to the element if the content of the element is larger than the elements client area minus any padding.  Getting rid of the scrollbars in CSS does exactly that.  It makes the scrollbars go away, no matter what.

The side effect of your work around is  if there is content outside of the client, the use will not be able to see it.  Additionally, this will not only happen with this form but every form in your application unless you apply your workaround in a custom class.

The right fix is to figure out why your content area is larger than the form's client area.  Firebug can be a big help with this as you can inspect the DOM and see the size of the container as well as the size of all the child items.

I suspect that  your clear selections control (is this a custom control?) is not properly sizing itself (i.e in your form layout you're telling it to be x pixels high but it's actually sizing itself x+1 (remember margins and padding).  The form layout is doing all the work to decide how big to make the wrapper area (the area with the scroll bar) and the control must fit within that area.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Looking further I found that the component's inner fieldset had a bottom margin of 10 pixels, which was obviously not factored into the component's height. I added a css class for fieldsets within this particular component that removed the bottom margin. Thanks again.

Comment: Reverted the content removed by author, because the answer was accepted and commented by OP.